# where does django REST API inherits 'users' from?

Tags: python, django, api

I've created an API with certain paraments and fed it to my django URL with the following sample..

```
def home(request):
    response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/workers/')
    workers = response.json()
    return render(request, "home.html", {'users': workers})
    pass
```

Where does it inherit the 'users' from?

my API doesn't contain anything related to it and I would like to add a second API ontop of such as :

`return render(request, "home.html", {'users': workers}, {'users': speciality})`

will not work
because `users` is already inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that you are setting the context for “users”, twice.
When you set context, think of it like *“nicknaming”*. You first give `workers`, the nickname `users`. And then it seems as though you’re also trying to give `specialty`, the nickname `users`.

They can’t both have the same name, or else one of them will be overwritten. Let’s break down what’s happening..

Original code:

```py
  workers = response.json()
  # Context: refer to workers as “users” in the template. 
  return render(request, "home.html", {'users': workers})
```

Desired code:

```py
# Context: refer to works as “users” in the template. Also refer to speciality as “users in the template.
return render(request, "home.html", {'users': workers}, {'users': speciality})
```

But also, check out [Django documentation on render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

```py
render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
```

You can’t define context in two separate dictionaries like in this example:

```py
return render(request, "home.html", {'users': workers}, {'users': speciality})
```

## Short Answer:

1. `workers` and `speciality` need to have different names.
2. `workers` and `speciality` need to be defined in a single context dictionary.

Maybe try something like this:

```py
return render(request, template_name="home.html", context={'users': workers, 'user_specialities': speciality})
```